# Use magic e in extend function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a basic Drop event handler like the following:

```
function Drop(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data=e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var child = $('[target_id="'+data+'"]').get(0);
    e.target.appendChild(child);
}
function DropHandler(){}
DropHandler.prototype={
        ...
    Drop : Drop
}
```

Create a new object and extend the basic drop handler:

```
function AdminDropHandler(){}
//Extend the DropHandler
extend(AdminDropHandler,DropHandler);
//Override Drop method in AdminDropHandler
AdminDropHandler.prototype.Drop=function(){
    DropHandler.prototype.Drop.apply(this,arguments);
    var parent_id = e.target.id;// not defined error
    ...
}
```

It can extend the function of `DropHandler` but the `e` that I use seems lose. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `e` in the function anywhere. Try defining it:

```
AdminDropHandler.prototype.Drop = function(e) {
    DropHandler.prototype.Drop.apply(this, arguments);
    var parent_id = e.target.id; // should work now
};
```

You can also do this, though it's not recommended because a formal parameter does the job 
just fine:

```
AdminDropHandler.prototype.Drop = function() {
    var e = arguments[0];
    DropHandler.prototype.Drop.apply(this, arguments);
    var parent_id = e.target.id; // should work now
};
```

Comment: isn't that in DropHandler.prototype.Drop? I pass the e into it. And wether will extend it when I call DropHandler.prototype.Drop.apply(this, arguments) ?

Comment: @PandaYang You pass `e` into it implicitly through `arguments`, it's not defined in the function itself. You can either use `var e = arguments[0];` or a formal parameter like I did. Calling some other function doesn't define variables in the calling function.

Comment: I see, so the e in AdminDropHandler.Drop becomes arguments[0] right?

Comment: @PandaYang There is no `e` automatically, you need to define it using one of the two methods I provided. Technically you could also use `arguments[0].target.id` but that's just ugly :P